# How can I compare two chars?

Tags: java, char, equals

Situation: I have two strings stored in a string array.

Goal: I want to add all the chars which are in both strings to a string variable `out`.

```
String out = "";
for(int i = 0; i < strArr[0].length(); i++){
    char x = strArr[0].charAt(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < strArr[1].length(); j++){
        char y = strArr[1].charAt(j);
        if(x.equals(y)){
            out.concat(x + ",");
        }
    }
}

if(out.equals("")){
    out = "false";
}
```

Problem: When I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
char cannot be dereferenced
        if(x.equals(y)){
            ^
```

I've also tried this:

```
if(x == y){
    out.concat(x + ",");
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: `if (x == y)` is the correct syntax to compare two `char`s. So it should compile fine.

Comment: Also note that `out.concat(x + ",");` does not modify `out`. Consider using a `StringBuilder` with `append`.

Comment: Use `x == y` to compare primitives and the `equals()` method to compare complex types!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "_it doesn't work_" ?

Comment: "But it doesn't work either." What exactly happened when you tried that, and how does it differ from what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

To compare two `char` values, use the == operator `x == y`.

The reason why it didn't *seem* to work is another: the `out.concat()` method you are using does not modify `out`. In general, String is "immutable" - you cannot change the value of a String.

Use StringBuilder instead of String for the `out` variable.

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < strArr[0].length(); i++){
    char x = strArr[0].charAt(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < strArr[1].length(); j++){
        char y = strArr[1].charAt(j);
        if (x == y){
            out.append(x + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare primitive types with `==`.

Strings are immutable.

Calling `out.concat("whatever")`doesn't change the value of `out`. You have to assign the returned value to `out`.

```
if(x == y){ // compare primitive with ==
    out = out.concat(x + ","); // assign the returned value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned the problem you are having with `String` being immutable, I would go a step further and suggest an alternate approach over iterating through your strings. `HashSet<T>` has two methods that should simplify your code. `addAll` and `retainAll`.

```
String out = "";

HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
hashSet.addAll(strArr[0]);
hashSet.retainAll(strArr[1]);

out = hashSet.toString();

if(out.equals("")){
    out = "false";
}
```